# font-awesome to be inserted in value="<spring:message text="View List"/>">

Tags: spring, button, input, font-awesome

im trying to insert some font-awesome inside here

```
<form action="/someweb.html">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="<spring:message text="View List"/>"> 
</form>
```

but it seems that this code

```
<i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-lg"></i>
```

wont fit inside, and i tried to insert it inside in different position, i always get failed result. all i wanted is to have this kind of look [here](http://prntscr.com/7fti5r).

hope you could help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the out you are expecting? `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="<i class='fa fa-list-ul fa-lg'></i>">` ?

Comment: nope. i tried this now,  it just gave me a button that shows the words/text <i class='fa fa-list-ul fa-lg'></i> inside. :(

Comment: that was a question i had. I didn't want you to try it. Anyway, my answer should give you a direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it completely, but this should give you an idea.

```
    <form action="/someweb.html">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class='fa fa-list-ul fa-lg'></i><spring:message text="View List"/></button>
    </form>
```

Here is a sample in codepen.

`http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNXvZw`

Comment: i tried this now and this is giving this look http://prntscr.com/7fub94
it should be inside the button :( tried to re-arranged it but im still not getting it inside the button. :(

Comment: Add it with a quote in comments. All i see in the link is `Browse image` button.

Comment: i tried this now and this is giving this look http://prntscr.com/7fub94 it should be inside the button :( tried to re-arranged it but im still not getting it inside the button. :(

Comment: @zansan I modified my answer already. Take a look at the codepen link i gave.

Comment: thanks so much @minion !!! :) the codepen link you gave worked!!! 

i tried the button method hours ago, maybe i had it in different order that is why its not working :) thanks!! :)

Comment: hi again, i hope you could also help me in this follow up question after using our solution here, here is the problem that followed after i applied this to the form. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790850/part-2-font-awesome-to-be-inserted-in-form-value-springmessage-text-add-art